# Translating C to IA-32 assembly - comparing w/ 2 conditions

Tags: c, translation, x86

I am translating code from C to IA-32 and I am stuck on one part. The line of code is this:

```
if ( (input != '0') && (input != '1') ) {
```

I know that for the first condition it would just be:

```
cmpl $0, %eax          #%eax is where my input is stored
```

but what about the second condition? I am not sure if I should just have another comparison or overthinking the problem or what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need a second comparison, following a jump for failure of the first condition. Just bear in mind `'0'` is `30h`; not `0`

Comment: @Petesh couple followup questions. Why is it 30h? Do I jump from the first condition to the second and if they both fail then another jump? Thanks for the response.

Comment: when you have `'0'` it means the *character* `0`, not the raw number `0`, so you look it up on your handy ascii table. You will need to test and jump on failure for the first clause of the `&&`. You will then need to test and jump on failure for the second clause of the `&&`. In the case that you jump, it's to the statement immediately after the closing `}` of the `if`.

Comment: You don't need 2 comparisons for this case. Optimizing compiler will emit only one jump for this. Look at https://gcc.godbolt.org/ output to know more

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc true, but writing something that works *first* and then think about optimizations. Hand-writing assembly is a common exercise in compiler writing courses to help understand things.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like:

```
           cmpl  $30, %eax    ; if '0' &&-expr must be false
           je    falsebit
           cmpl  $31, %eax    ; if '1' &&-expr must be false
           je    falsebit
truebit:
           ; do something here - it is neither '0' nor '1'
falsebit:
           ; skip point
```